# Convert Windows relative path to POSIX relative path so I can join POSIX absolute path and Windows relative path

Tags: python, windows, path, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm looking for a platform-independent solution. Everything works on Linux because `os.walk` already returns POSIX paths. However, if I'm on Windows I might get the following two paths:

```
abspath = "/x/y/z" # given path for a remote server which uses POSIX paths
relpath = "a\\b\\c" # acquired from local file system via os.walk, so it uses slash or backslash depending on the platform
```

The desired result of the joined path for this example would be:

```
'/x/y/z/a/b/c'
```

However, naturally, using `posixpath.join` results in:

```
>>> posixpath.join(abspath, relpath)
'/x/y/z/a\\b\\c'
```

So when I'm on Windows and have a relative path like `a\\b\\c`, I think it might make sense to convert it to a POSIX relative path `a/b/c` first, so I am able to use `posixpath.join` afterwards?

However, I don't believe simply replacing every backslash with a slash is best practice - or is it? I couldn't find any function which provides such a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `os` which depends on the platform, or `posixpath` which will only work with POSIX paths, Python's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module seems to be a good choice here:

> This module offers classes representing filesystem paths with semantics appropriate for different operating systems

Here is a solution for the example from the question above:

```
import pathlib
def example(abspath, relpath):
    abspath = pathlib.PurePosixPath(abspath)
    relpath = pathlib.PurePath(relpath)
    return str(abspath / relpath)
```

`pathlib.PurePosixPath` is being used for `abspath` because the final path is supposed to be a POSIX path and [`pathlib.PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath) works on both Windows and Linux:

> `pathlib.PurePath` - A generic class that represents the system’s path flavour (instantiating it creates either a `PurePosixPath` or a `PureWindowsPath`)

An example call on Linux might look like:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
>>> example("/x/y/z", "a/b/c")
'/x/y/z/a/b/c'
```

An example call on Windows might look like:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Windows'
>>> example("/x/y/z", "a\\b\\c")
'/x/y/z/a/b/c'
```

So it produces the correct POSIX path on both platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `pathlib.Path`, it handles the tricky parts of manipulating paths across platforms.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

```py
from pathlib import Path, PosixPath


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BASE_DIR = Path('/path/to/base')
    rel_path = r'path\to\rel'
    print(BASE_DIR)
    print(rel_path)
    print(BASE_DIR / rel_path)
```

output:

```
\path\to\base
path\to\rel
\path\to\base\path\to\rel
```

Comment: Since I'm on Windows all paths convert to windows-style paths with `\ ` as separator. On POSIX systems it should convert to `/` separators

Comment: The fact that python doesn't let me instantiate it on Windows. It only allows WindowsPath to be instantiated.

Comment: I haven't tried it, really. If that works, use it. Keep in mind that you have the ability to join paths using `/` operator, you don't have to use `joinpath() ` method.